# sending emails after every 2 minute to the email addresses from excelsheet

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, sidekiq, delayed-job

Want to send emails after every 2 minute to the email addresses from excelsheet.

I tried using sidekiq and delayed_job but emails are shooting after a delay but at same time.

Tried delay, delay_for and some methods but not helping

worker file

```
class MarketingEmailsWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker 
def perform(*args)
    EmailList.read_file(args)
end
```

end

`EmailList.rb` model

```
def self.read_file(record)
    list = EmailList.find(record).last
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(list.file.path, extension: :xlsx)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        email = row["Email"]   
        if email.present?                                                                                                                                                                                 
            geography= row["Geography"].to_s
            lname = row["Name"]
            designation = row["Designation"]
            Notifier.send_template_mail(geography,email,lname,designation,list.emails_template).deliver_now
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Codewise there is not really a viable option just something weird like

```
def perform(*args)
  while true do
    EmailList.read_file(args)
    sleep(120) # 2 minutes in seconds
  end
end
```

But **I don't recommend it for any production system**. Since you can't really control that worker.

---

**Better way**

of solving this would be using some [scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler)
There you can setup a yml with cron like sidekiq workers.
There are plenty of options to get your workers scheduled e.g. `cron: '*/2 * * * *'` or `every: '2m'`.

There is also a scheduler option for [delayed_job](https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring) with a solid documentation.

Take in to account that as soon your worker takes longer than 2 minutes to process you will pile up workers in your queue.

Comment: I already tried `sleep` option but will not be using for production server. Will give a try to `scheduler`. As records are coming from excelsheet and not from database, I am not able to keep track of how many emails are sent.

Comment: Keeping track how many emails were sent is a completely other topic and wasn't mentioned in your question.